# R output from RFacebook

Tags: r, facebook, dataframe

I'm using the RFacebook package and I'm having trouble with the output. Trying to use the package to scrape a page for everyone who's liked a post. I'm able to use a for loop to create a data frame, however the output looks pretty weird and I'm wondering if anyone can help me format it differently.

Here's my code

```
post1<- ""
for (i in page$id){
  post<- getPost(i, token, n = 1000,
                 likes = TRUE, comments = FALSE)
  liker <- as.list(post$likes[1])
  post1 <- rbind(post1,liker)
}
```

Here's the data frame that results

[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJZjV.png)

The end goal here is to create a frame that has the person's name, and next to it would be the amount of posts they've liked. That part will be fairly easy as I can check how many times they're name is found, but I'm not able to do that with the current format the frame is in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for rFacebook, the getPost function returns three things; the post, a dataframe of comments, and a dataframe of likes.

> getPost returns a list with three components: post, likes, and comments. First, post contains
>   information about the post: author, creation date, id, counts of likes, comments, and shares, etc.
>   Second, likes is a data frame that contains names and Facebook IDs of all the users that liked the
>   post. Finally, comments is a data frame with information about the comments to the post (author,
>   message, creation time, id)

In your function you access the likes dataframe  `liker <- as.list(post$likes[1])`, but you only take the first element of what is presumably a 2d dataframe. The data you are looking for might be found in `post$likes$from_name`

Comment: So that produces interesting results. Yes, it produces a clean data frame, but I get errors, and the many names get left off the error is " : In rbind(post1, liker) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)"

Comment: Thats because the `liker` vector is of variable length, while the dataframe you are trying to rbind to has a set number of columns. This is why I suggest rbinding the dataframes together, so that there is a row for each 'liker' alternatively you could store them as a vector `post1 <- c(post1,liker)`